# NSPredicate filter for less than OR nil

Tags: swift, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I want NSPredicate to give me back results for a keyPath that is either nil... or less than a given date. I'm using the NSPredicate for core data.

These are working correctly...

```
let endDatePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K > %@", #keyPath(RepeatingTask.endDate), date as NSDate)
let endDatePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == nil", #keyPath(RepeatingTask.endDate), date as NSDate)
```

But I can't get these to work correctly with an OR operator...

```
let endDatePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K > %@ || %K == nil", #keyPath(RepeatingTask.endDate), date as NSDate)
let endDatePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K > %@ OR %K == nil", #keyPath(RepeatingTask.endDate), date as NSDate)
let endDatePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(%K > %@) || (%K == nil)", #keyPath(RepeatingTask.endDate), date as NSDate)
```

Comment: There are two `%K`  specifiers in your predicate format string, so you must also pass two key paths as arguments: `NSPredicate(format: "%K > %@ OR %K == nil", #keyPath(RepeatingTask.endDate), date as NSDate, #keyPath(RepeatingTask.endDate))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [NSCompoundPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscompoundpredicate). For example:

```
let first = NSPredicate(format: "%K > %@", #keyPath(RepeatingTask.endDate), date as NSDate)
let second = NSPredicate(format: "%K == nil", #keyPath(RepeatingTask.endDate), date as NSDate)
let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [first, second])
```